# How to Remove + Sign From dropdown from bundle product?

Tags: magento2.3.4, dropdown-options

**how can we remove +(Plus) sign from Dropdown list from bundle product?
in Magento 2.3.4**

i have tried this link but its not work for me..  [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44538216/how-to-remove-sign-from-customizable-option-from-front-view-in-magento2)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Please override below file
>
> vendor\magento\module-bundle\Block\Catalog\Product\View\Type\Bundle\Option.php
>
> Here you will see `getSelectionTitlePrice()` function just remove **+**
> symbol and try it.
>
> Now after removing **+** sign you have take care when you will add product
> to cart. That time you have to check next functionality where it's
> processing the data.

Comment: i have tried this but, when I select an option from the dropdown, +sign appeared automatically,

Comment: @rakesh.sumeshara, means inside dropdown  *+* has been removed.

Comment: yes it was removed when page is load,but after when we select any option from dropdown it was appear automatically